# One pixel line in silverlight application

Tags: .net, silverlight, drawing

I want to draw one pixel line in my silverlight (4.0) application.

I use next wpf code:

```
<Canvas  Name="CanvasRoot" Height="4000">
                <Line X1="0" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="10" Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Aqua" Fill="#FF903F3F"></Line> 
            </Canvas>
```

but it does not allow me to create real one pixel line.
I mean here line which has one pixel weight when I rotate it.
I tried to set StrokeThickness to 0.5, but it did not help me.
Suggest me please how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Probably UseLayoutRounding=false will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle with 1px height should do the trick.

```
<Rectangle Height="1" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100" Fill="#FF903F3F" />
```